# Why did Guy break into Bruno's house?

Tags: plot-explanation, strangers-on-a-train

In the movie "Strangers on a Train", we see Guy entering Bruno's house at night, using the key and the map and carrying the gun, all of which Bruno had given him earlier. Then we know that he's just going to talk to Bruno's father about his son's madness and has no intention to kill him.

I simply don't get it! Why in the middle of the night? Why in the father's (supposed) bedroom and not anywhere else? Why while carrying a gun?

Comment: I believe he is trying to *warn his father, not simply talk to him. He's taking a risk and felt it was immediate that he do so He didn't want to get caught. As a psychological thriller, it makes sense there would be scenes to generate suspense and things should feel "pressing". I don't think he knows if Bruno's father knows about Bruno or not, but he believes not...

Comment: He may have taken the gun to prove to the father that Bruno gave it to him. I admit the rest seems like irrational behavior that's simply there to fake us out.